# How to handle the onRelease event using ionic2 components?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, whatsapp

I'm trying to create a button similar to **WhatsApp** voice note button. that onHold the voice is recording and onRelease you can do anything.

I searched in ionic2 [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/). I did found any directive that handle the onRelease event.

I found a piece that is work properly.

```
  @Output('long-press') onPress: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter();
  @Output('long-press-up') onPressUp: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter();




  ngOnInit() {
    this.pressGesture = new Gesture(this.htmlElement);
    this.pressGesture.listen();

    this.pressGesture.on('press', (event) => {
      this.recordVoice();
      this.onPress.emit(event);
    });

    this.pressGesture.on('pressup', (event) => {
      this.stopRecording();
      this.onPressUp.emit(event);
    });
  }
```

COMPONENT

```
        <button type="button" clear item-right (long-press)="longPressed()" (long-press-up)="longPressReleased()">
          <ion-icon name="mic"></ion-icon>
        </button>
```

But What wrong is when I hold any place an the screen `this.recordVoice()` is executed and once I release my finger `this.stopRecording()` is executed.

What I need the onPress and onPressUp to be executed just for the button and not the whole page.

So I how to modify the code above to fix what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need and I end-ed up to use that plugin: https://github.com/wbhob/ionic-long-press

Then you can do like this:

```
<button ion-button 
    ion-long-press 
    [interval]="400" 
    (onPressStart)="recordVoice()" 
    (onPressing)="recording()" 
    (onPressEnd)="stopRecording()"></button>
```